# perl6 How to read from stdin and take command line args?

Tags: stdin, args, raku

I need to pipe the result of "cat variousFiles" to a perl6 program while requiring the program to take different command line arguments. Perl6 seems to want to take the first argument as a file to be read. I can re-write my routines, but I want to use a pipe from shell. Is there a way to do it?

Here is my program named testStdInArgs.pl:

```
say @*ARGS;
for lines() {
    say "reading ==> ", $_;
}
```

I want to do (foo and bar are arguments):

```
cat logFile | perl6 testStdInArgs.pl foo bar
```

Here are the errors:

```
[foo bar]
Earlier failure:
 (HANDLED) Unable to open file 'foo'
  in block <unit> at stdInArgs.pl line 2

Final error:
 Type check failed in binding to $iter; expected Iterator but got Failure (Failure.new(exception...)
  in block <unit> at stdInArgs.pl line 2
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `lines` function is a shortcut for `$*ARGFILES.lines`.
`$*ARGFILES` is a magic file handle that represents a concatenation of the files specified as command-line arguments (`@*ARGS`), and falls back to stdin only if `@*ARGS` is empty.

If you always want to read from stdin, use `$*IN.lines`:

```
for $*IN.lines {
    say "reading ==> $_";
}
```

Alternatively, let your code modify `@*ARGS` to remove any command-line arguments that you don't want to be interpreted as filenames, and **then** use `lines()`.

Comment: I see ! Thank you smls !!! $*ARGFILES is something new I learned from you today. Thank you bery much !! Always something new to learn everyday (even if  I am not in the tech/IT field).